# Viewing Part of a figure

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I made a simulation of 10000 times and want to view part of simulation between 5000-5200. I am able to view it with the code below, but the x-axis says 0-250. I want the x-axis to display the exact figure of 5000-5200. Also there seems to be a small gap at the end of the figure as the axis runs up to 250 for some reason. I just want to view the figure in for this set time with the x-axis showing the exact labels and without the gap at the end.

Thanks

```
N=10000;%Number of simulation
P=0.02;
Q = zeros(N,1); %current value of queue
X=zeros(N,1);%simulation data
Ci=0;
L=0.9;
Bu=zeros(N,1);
Bs=30;
Bd1=50;
Bd2=270;
Ti=0;
for Ti=2:N
U=rand(1);
a=log10(U);
b=log10(1-P);
c=(a/b);
d=1+c;   
X(Ti)=round(d);
Ci=Ci+1;
if X(Ti)< (L)*(Bs)
      Bu(Ti)=Bs;
 else  if X(Ti) < (L)*(Bs+Bd1)
    Bu(Ti)=Bs+Bd1;
 else 
    Bu(Ti)=Bs+Bd1+Bd2;    
    end 
end
Ti=Ti+1;
end
plot(X(5000:5200,1),'r');
set (gca,'ylim',[0 400]);
hold on;
plot(Bu(5000:5200,1),'b');
set (gca,'ylim',[0 400]);
hold off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot expects two inputs, the first depicting the horizontal axis and the second depicting the vertical axis. When you do not supply two inputs, then it computes the length of the single input (in this case that length is 5200-5000 = 200), and it just uses 1 through that length (1:200 in this case) as if it is the values for the horizontal axis variable.

I think you want to issue the command:

```
plot(5000:5200, X(5000:5200,1), 'r')
```

Often Matlab will adjust plot axes for better default views, so it's probably showing the axis out to the index 250 just by virtue of some default plotting convention. You can similarly use `set(gca, 'xlim', [5000 5200])` if you wish.